# How to achieve Google Maps-like scrolling behavior on Here Maps API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I am using Here's Maps API for JavaScript and trying to achieve a scrolling behavior on mobile similar to what Google Map's API's has.

**When I want to scroll by touching the map, scrolling the page should not be always prevented, only if the Map's DRAGGING behavior is disabled**.

I have tried calling `window.scroll()` with the corresponding Y parameters extracted from pointer events, but it is not as smooth as the browser's default scrolling.

How should I use `drag` or some other event targeting the Map to scroll the page?

Comment: Hi, can you add some screenshots to show what you want to achieve please.

Comment: Here is a screen record: [link](https://ibb.co/MGsg81y). In this case, dragging is disabled by calling `this.behavior.isEnabled(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING)`. What I want to achieve is to scroll over the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
let mapevents = new mapsjs.mapevents.MapEvents(map),
    behavior = new mapsjs.mapevents.Behavior(mapevents);

let startY, endY = 0;
map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(evt) {
  if (evt.currentPointer.type == 'touch' && evt.pointers.length < 2) {
    startY = evt.currentPointer.viewportY;
    behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
  }
});

map.addEventListener('drag', function(evt) {
  if (evt.currentPointer.type == 'touch' && evt.pointers.length < 2) {
    endY = evt.currentPointer.viewportY;
    window.scrollBy(0, (startY - endY));
  }
});

map.addEventListener('dragend', function(evt) {
  behavior.enable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
});
```

In `dragstart` and `drag` callbacks the scrolling is disabled only when pointer's type is `touch` and number of pointers is 1. That makes it possible to zoom & pan the map with two fingers on touch device and also with mouse on desktops / laptops.

Note, that method `behavior.isEnabled(feature)` doesn't disable the feature. For that you need to use `behavior.disable(opt_features)` See https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-mapevents-behavior.html

Answer (score 1):

You can allow scrolling on the map by:

1. Disable the map's dragging behavior on `dragstart` and capture the Y coordinate.
2. Enable the map's dragging behavior on `dragend` and capture the Y coordinate.
3. Scroll the page by the difference of the start and end Y coordinates on `dragend`.

> ```
> var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);
> var beh = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);
> var startY, endY = 0;
> map.addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
>    startY = evt.currentPointer.viewportY;
>    beh.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
> });
>
> map.addEventListener("dragend", function(evt) {
>    endY = evt.currentPointer.viewportY;
>    window.scrollBy(0, (startY - endY));
>    beh.enable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
> });
> ```